# Do I have to explicitly update iTunes Match after adding new tracks to my Library?

Tags: itunes-match

Yesterday I set up iTunes Match, and before the day was over it Matched and/or Uploaded all of the tracks in my library at the time. Just now I added a few more tracks and they're currently listed as 'Waiting'.

Will iTunes Match eventually act on these new tracks automatically? Or will I have to explicitly go into the Store menu and choose 'Update iTunes Match'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose "Update iTunes Match" from the "Store" menu.