# How to refresh iCloud after some changes in iTunes

Tags: itunes, icloud

I use iCloud to sync music files. On my Mac, I changed some song information such as genre or artist name. How can I sync the changes on my Mac's iTunes with iCloud so that all my iPad and iPhone iTunes have the same change?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31452/do-i-have-to-explicitly-update-itunes-match-after-adding-new-tracks-to-my-librar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know these changes should be applied automatically. If not, try Store -> "Update iTunes Match" to apply the changes. You can also use "Add to iCloud" for songs which haven't been matched before.

Answer (score 0):

On an iPhone, turn on cellular data and turn off/on the iCloud Sync. First it will delete all of your local copies, then it will sync the new playlists and albums. Ensure it does not allow the album downloads over cellular, as charges may apply.